# Avoid Alert message in the first render React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have this code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { getTopicsByDcResponsable, getTopicsbyDcentroEdit, } from '../../slices/topicsSlice';
import CorpusNameCard from "./CorpusNameCard";
import { getAccessTokenApi } from "../../api/auth";
import { setToken } from "../../slices/userSlice";
import { setGeneralInfo } from '../../slices/faqsGeneralInfoSlice.js';
import { setVariationsResponse } from "../../slices/variationsSlice";


const CorpusNameFit = () => {   
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  dispatch(setGeneralInfo({
    description: '',
    typeResponse:  '',
    rolViews:  '',
    workLoadLevel:  '',
    id:  '',
    id_intent: '',
    corpusArea: '',
    corpusName: '' ,
    lateral_W:  '',
    simpleResponseNolist:  '',
  }));

  dispatch(setVariationsResponse({id: '',
    idResponse: '',
    description: '',
    examples_new: [],
    examples_edit: [],
    examples_production: [],
    timestamp_create: '',
    timestamp_update: ''
  }));
  

  const accessToken = getAccessTokenApi();  
  dispatch(setToken(accessToken));
    
  const { user } = useAuth();
  
  const {
    responsable,
    editor,
    matricula
  } = user; 
  
  const respDc = JSON.parse(responsable);
  const editDc = JSON.parse(editor);

  const getTopics= [];

  const getTopicsResponsable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector((state)=> state.topics.userTopics.responsableTopics)));
  for (let i of getTopicsResponsable){
    i['author'] = 'responsable';
    getTopics.push(i);
  }
  const getTopicsEditor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector((state)=> state.topics.userTopics.editorTopics)));
  for (let i of getTopicsEditor){
    i['author'] = 'editor';
    if(getTopics.findIndex(topic=>topic.topicName === i.topicName) === -1){ getTopics.push(i); }
  }   
 

  let topics = getTopics.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.topicName === o.topicName && obj.workspace_id === o.workspace_id && obj.author === o.author )) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
  },[]);
  
  const initFetch = useCallback(() => {
    for (let dc of respDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsByDcResponsable(dc));      
    }
    for (let dc of editDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit(dc));
    }  
  }, [dispatch]);    
    
 
    
  useEffect(() => {    
    if(matricula) {       
      initFetch();}  
  }, [matricula] ); 
  

  if (getTopics === undefined) return null;
  console.log(topics);
  return (
    <div className="container" >
      <div className="subheader-bar">
        <h1 className="subheader-bar__title">Gestión del conocimiento</h1>
        <p className="subheader-bar__info">Estas son las temáticas que tienes asociadas a tu usuario. Selecciona la que quieras consultar.</p>
      </div>       
      <div className="row row-cols-1 justify-content-center row-cols-md-3 g-4 mt-5 mb-5">
        {topics.length !== 0 ? topics.map(topic => <CorpusNameCard key={topic.topicName} topic={topic.topicName} workspace_id={topic.workspace_id} author={topic.author}/>) :          
          <div className="alert alert-warning" role='alert'>
           <h4 className="text-center"> 
              No Tienes Ningún Topic Asociado.
              Contacta con tu Responsable
            </h4>
          </div>            
        }        
      </div>
    </div>    
        
  );
};

export default CorpusNameFit;
```

The thing is when a load the page in the first render, show the alert that says that i don't have Corpus. Then after the dispatch, the second render show the corpus.
I would like to know how can i avoid this first render or how to avoid to show the alert after the dispatches that get me the topics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the check `topics.length !== 0` fails and the warning section is displayed. Sounds like you should add a state of "initializing" (until `initFetch` finishes to run) which will default to `true` and check that state as well. Once the application was loaded in the first time: change `initializing` to `false`.

Something like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { getTopicsByDcResponsable, getTopicsbyDcentroEdit, } from '../../slices/topicsSlice';
import CorpusNameCard from "./CorpusNameCard";
import { getAccessTokenApi } from "../../api/auth";
import { setToken } from "../../slices/userSlice";
import { setGeneralInfo } from '../../slices/faqsGeneralInfoSlice.js';
import { setVariationsResponse } from "../../slices/variationsSlice";


const CorpusNameFit = () => {   
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(); /// HERE

  dispatch(setGeneralInfo({
    description: '',
    typeResponse:  '',
    rolViews:  '',
    workLoadLevel:  '',
    id:  '',
    id_intent: '',
    corpusArea: '',
    corpusName: '' ,
    lateral_W:  '',
    simpleResponseNolist:  '',
  }));

  dispatch(setVariationsResponse({id: '',
    idResponse: '',
    description: '',
    examples_new: [],
    examples_edit: [],
    examples_production: [],
    timestamp_create: '',
    timestamp_update: ''
  }));
  

  const accessToken = getAccessTokenApi();  
  dispatch(setToken(accessToken));
    
  const { user } = useAuth();
  
  const {
    responsable,
    editor,
    matricula
  } = user; 
  
  const respDc = JSON.parse(responsable);
  const editDc = JSON.parse(editor);

  const getTopics= [];

  const getTopicsResponsable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector((state)=> state.topics.userTopics.responsableTopics)));
  for (let i of getTopicsResponsable){
    i['author'] = 'responsable';
    getTopics.push(i);
  }
  const getTopicsEditor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector((state)=> state.topics.userTopics.editorTopics)));
  for (let i of getTopicsEditor){
    i['author'] = 'editor';
    if(getTopics.findIndex(topic=>topic.topicName === i.topicName) === -1){ getTopics.push(i); }
  }   
 

  let topics = getTopics.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.topicName === o.topicName && obj.workspace_id === o.workspace_id && obj.author === o.author )) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
  },[]);
  
  const initFetch = useCallback(() => {
    for (let dc of respDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsByDcResponsable(dc));      
    }
    for (let dc of editDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit(dc));
    }  
  }, [dispatch]);    
    
 
    
  useEffect(() => {    
    if(matricula) {       
      initFetch();
      setInitializing(false);  /// HERE
    }  
  }, [matricula] ); 
  

  if (getTopics === undefined) return null;
  console.log(topics);

  if (!initializing && topics.length === 0) {                       /// HERE
      return (<div className="alert alert-warning" role='alert'>
           <h4 className="text-center"> 
              No Tienes Ningún Topic Asociado.
              Contacta con tu Responsable
            </h4>
          </div>  );
  }

  if (initializing) {
    return <div><p>Loading...</p></div>
  }

  return (
    <div className="container" >
      <div className="subheader-bar">
        <h1 className="subheader-bar__title">Gestión del conocimiento</h1>
        <p className="subheader-bar__info">Estas son las temáticas que tienes asociadas a tu usuario. Selecciona la que quieras consultar.</p>
      </div>       
      <div className="row row-cols-1 justify-content-center row-cols-md-3 g-4 mt-5 mb-5">
        
        {topics.map(topic => <CorpusNameCard key={topic.topicName} topic={topic.topicName} workspace_id={topic.workspace_id} author={topic.author}/>)}                        
        }        
      </div>
    </div>    
        
  );
};

export default CorpusNameFit
```

Comment: appreciated your response, but still when i refresh the page i see the alert, now after the initializing message. maybe i need to make something like, first load, then print (objects or alert)

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions SGTM: while loading you should display something else and only after you have the data you should try to display it. I updated the code a bit - can you give it another try?

Comment: is not exact like i would like, but your ideas give me a new vision. Now i try to put a settimeout, to show 'Loading....? and then after retrieve or not the topics, show them or show the alert.